# American Checkers

Tags: game, functional-programming, f#, checkers-draughts

I am implementing the logic for a Checkers game in F#.  I am writing my code in a library so it can be called from any UI provider, and am trying to do it in good FP style.  I currently have the following code; each file is provided in the order of compilation:

**Checkers.fs** This contains some unions and records that will be used throughout the entire library.

```
type Player = Black | White

type PieceType = Checker | King

type Coord = {
    Row :int
    Column :int
} with
    static member (+) (coord1 :Coord, coord2 :Coord) =
        {Row = coord1.Row + coord2.Row; Column = coord1.Column + coord2.Column}
```

**Piece.fs** This is an immutable class representing a Piece. It contains each option as a static member to ease building boards manually.

```
type Piece(player:Player, pieceType:PieceType) =
    member this.Player = player
    member this.PieceType = pieceType

    member this.Promote() =
        new Piece(player, PieceType.King)

    override this.Equals (obj) =
        let piece = obj :?> Piece
        piece.Player = this.Player &&
        piece.PieceType = this.PieceType

    override this.GetHashCode() =
        this.Player.GetHashCode() ^^^ this.PieceType.GetHashCode()

    static member WhiteChecker() =
        Some <| new Piece(Player.White, PieceType.Checker)

    static member BlackChecker() =
        Some <| new Piece(Player.Black, PieceType.Checker)

    static member WhiteKing() =
        Some <| new Piece(Player.White, PieceType.King)

    static member BlackKing() =
        Some <| new Piece(Player.Black, PieceType.King)
```

**Board.fs** This type represents a board, and the only stateful member of this class is immutable, like `Piece`.  The second optional constructor is for ease of creating a board from a hard-coded list in C#; it may not remain in future versions.

```
type Board(board) =
    new () = Board(Board.DefaultBoard)

    new(board :IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Option<Piece>>>) =
        let boardArray = List.ofSeq(board.Select(fun r -> List.ofSeq(r)))
        Board(boardArray)

    member this.Board :Option<Piece> list list = board

    member this.Item
        with get(coord :Coord) =
            this.Board.[coord.Row].[coord.Column]

    member this.Item
        with get(row :int) =
            this.Board.[row]

    static member DefaultBoard :Option<Piece> list list =
        [
            [None; Piece.BlackChecker(); None; Piece.BlackChecker(); None; Piece.BlackChecker(); None; Piece.BlackChecker()];
            [Piece.BlackChecker(); None; Piece.BlackChecker(); None; Piece.BlackChecker(); None; Piece.BlackChecker(); None];
            [None; Piece.BlackChecker(); None; Piece.BlackChecker(); None; Piece.BlackChecker(); None; Piece.BlackChecker()];
            [None; None; None; None; None; None; None; None];
            [None; None; None; None; None; None; None; None];
            [Piece.WhiteChecker(); None; Piece.WhiteChecker(); None; Piece.WhiteChecker(); None; Piece.WhiteChecker(); None];
            [None; Piece.WhiteChecker(); None; Piece.WhiteChecker(); None; Piece.WhiteChecker(); None; Piece.WhiteChecker()];
            [Piece.WhiteChecker(); None; Piece.WhiteChecker(); None; Piece.WhiteChecker(); None; Piece.WhiteChecker(); None];
        ];
```

**FSharpExtensions.fs** This module contains many functions for internal use only. Most of these functions are designed to be based on a certain type to make calling them easier; perhaps they should be included in the type rather than being extensions like this?

```
module FSharpExtensions =

    let internal getJumpedCoord(startCoord, endCoord) =
        {Row = startCoord.Row - Math.Sign(startCoord.Row - endCoord.Row); Column = startCoord.Column - Math.Sign(startCoord.Column - endCoord.Column)}

    let internal checkMoveDirection(piece :Piece, startCoord :Coord, endCoord :Coord) =
        match piece.PieceType with
        | PieceType.Checker ->
            match piece.Player with
            | Player.Black -> startCoord.Row < endCoord.Row
            | Player.White -> startCoord.Row > endCoord.Row
        | PieceType.King -> true

    let internal moveIsDiagonal(startCoord :Coord, endCoord :Coord) =
        startCoord <> endCoord &&
        System.Math.Abs(startCoord.Row - endCoord.Row) = System.Math.Abs(startCoord.Column - endCoord.Column)

    let internal kingRowIndex(player) =
        match player with
        | Player.Black -> 7
        | Player.White -> 0

    type Board with
        member internal board.CoordExists(coord :Coord) =
            coord.Row > 0 && coord.Row < board.Board.Length &&
            coord.Column > 0 && coord.Column < board.Board.[0].Length

        member internal board.IsValidCheckerHop(startCoord :Coord, endCoord :Coord) =
            let piece = board.[startCoord].Value

            checkMoveDirection(piece, startCoord, endCoord) &&
            board.[endCoord].IsNone

        member internal board.IsValidKingHop(startCoord :Coord, endCoord :Coord) =
            board.[endCoord].IsNone

        member internal board.IsValidCheckerJump(startCoord :Coord, endCoord :Coord) =
            let piece = board.[startCoord].Value

            let jumpedCoord = getJumpedCoord(startCoord, endCoord)
            let jumpedPiece = board.[jumpedCoord]

            checkMoveDirection(piece, startCoord, endCoord) &&
            board.[endCoord].IsNone &&
            jumpedPiece.IsSome &&
            jumpedPiece.Value.Player <> piece.Player

        member internal board.IsValidKingJump(startCoord :Coord, endCoord :Coord) =
            let piece = board.[startCoord].Value

            let jumpedCoord = getJumpedCoord(startCoord, endCoord)
            let jumpedPiece = board.[jumpedCoord]

            board.[endCoord].IsNone &&
            jumpedPiece.IsSome &&
            jumpedPiece.Value.Player <> piece.Player

        member internal board.IsValidHop(startCoord :Coord, endCoord :Coord) =
            match board.[startCoord].Value.PieceType with
            | PieceType.Checker -> board.IsValidCheckerHop(startCoord, endCoord)
            | PieceType.King -> board.IsValidKingHop(startCoord, endCoord)

        member internal board.IsValidJump(startCoord :Coord, endCoord :Coord) =
            match board.[startCoord].Value.PieceType with
            | PieceType.Checker -> board.IsValidCheckerJump(startCoord, endCoord)
            | PieceType.King -> board.IsValidKingJump(startCoord, endCoord)

        member internal board.SetPieceAt(coord :Coord, piece :Option<Piece>) =
            let boardItems = List.init 8 (fun row ->
                match row with
                | i when i = coord.Row ->
                    List.init 8 (fun col ->
                        match col with
                        | j when j = coord.Column -> piece
                        | _ -> board.[row].[col]
                    )
                | _ -> board.[row]
            )
            new Board(boardItems)

        member internal board.Jump(startCoord :Coord, endCoord :Coord) =
            let kingRowIndex = kingRowIndex(board.[startCoord].Value.Player)

            let piece =
                match endCoord.Row with
                | row when row = kingRowIndex -> Some <| board.[startCoord].Value.Promote()
                | _ -> board.[startCoord]

            let jumpedCoord = getJumpedCoord(startCoord, endCoord)

            board.SetPieceAt(startCoord, None).SetPieceAt(endCoord, piece).SetPieceAt(jumpedCoord, None)

        member internal board.Hop(startCoord :Coord, endCoord :Coord) =
            let kingRowIndex = kingRowIndex(board.[startCoord].Value.Player)

            let piece =
                match endCoord.Row with
                | row when row = kingRowIndex -> Some <| board.[startCoord].Value.Promote()
                | _ -> board.[startCoord]

            board.SetPieceAt(startCoord, None).SetPieceAt(endCoord, piece)
```

**ExtensionMethods.fs** This is really the public API of my library.  I designed the methods like this so they could be called as `boardInstance.Member(...)` in both C# and F#.

```
[<Extension>]
type ExtensionMethods() =

    [<Extension>]
    static member IsValidMove(board :Board, startCoord :Coord, endCoord :Coord) =
        board.CoordExists(startCoord) &&
        board.CoordExists(endCoord) &&
        board.[startCoord].IsSome &&
        moveIsDiagonal(startCoord, endCoord) &&
        match Math.Abs(startCoord.Row - endCoord.Row) with
        | 1 -> board.IsValidHop(startCoord, endCoord)
        | 2 -> board.IsValidJump(startCoord, endCoord)
        | _ -> false

    [<Extension>]
    static member Move(board :Board, startCoord :Coord, endCoord :Coord) :Option<Board> =
        match ExtensionMethods.IsValidMove(board, startCoord, endCoord) with
        | false -> None
        | true ->
            match Math.Abs(startCoord.Row - endCoord.Row) with
            | 1 -> Some <| board.Hop (startCoord, endCoord)
            | 2 -> Some <| board.Jump (startCoord, endCoord)
            | _ -> None

    [<Extension>]
    static member Move(board :Board, coordinates :IEnumerable<Coord>) =
        let coords = List.ofSeq(coordinates)

        match coords.Length with
        | b when b >= 3 ->
            let newBoard = ExtensionMethods.Move (board, coords.Head, coords.[1])
            ExtensionMethods.Move (newBoard, coords.Tail)
        | _ -> ExtensionMethods.Move (board, coords.Head, coords.[1])

    static member internal Move(board :Option<Board>, coordinates :IEnumerable<Coord>) =
        match board.IsSome with
        | false -> None
        | true -> ExtensionMethods.Move(board.Value, coordinates)
```

Any and all comments welcome.  If you see something that I can improve, or that I am not doing something the idiomatic F# way, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the many benefits of F# is that it's a multiparadigmatic language; while it embraces a *functional-first* ideal, it clearly also enables you to write object-oriented code. This is useful if you're coming from a C# background, like I did some years ago. You can get started quickly writing F#, concentrating on learning the language syntax. Naturally, if you do that, you'd tend to start your F# journey writing F# in an object-oriented style. There's nothing wrong with that; it's part of the voyage.

It looks like you've already made an effort to make your F# code immutable, which is an important step in the right direction. In general, it's looking good.

You also use the word *idiomatic F#*, and that opens another discussion. Most importantly, [what's idiomatic has a subjective component](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/08/03/idiomatic-or-idiosyncratic). Still, when I write F# code these days, my code is mostly assembled from functional types (records, discriminated unions, lists, tuples) and `let`-bound functions. Most of the code I've seen from other seasoned F# programmers seem to follow that pattern as well. With that in mind, here are some suggestions that would, in my opinion, make the code more idiomatic.

**Use functional types**

You already start by declaring the two record types `Player` and `PieceType`, and that's a good start, but why make `Coord` a class? You can make it a record, too:

```
type Coord = { Row :int; Column :int }
```

You can still support addition:

```
let (+) coord1 coord2 =
    { Row = coord1.Row + coord2.Row; Column = coord1.Column + coord2.Column }
```

Notice how type annotations aren't required. Since this function reads from `Row` and `Column` labels, the compiler can infer that both `coord1` and `coord2` are `Coord` values.

The `+` function still works, as this FSI session demonstrates:

```
> { Row = 1; Column = 4 } + { Row = 2; Column = 3 };;
val it : Coord = {Row = 3; Column = 7;}
```

In the same spirit, it's easy to refactor `Piece` to a record and associated functions:

```
type Piece = { Player : Player; PieceType : PieceType }

let promote p = { p with PieceType = King }

let whiteChecker = Some { Player = White; PieceType = Checker }

let blackChecker = Some { Player = Black; PieceType = Checker }

let whiteKing    = Some { Player = White; PieceType = King }

let blackKing    = Some { Player = Black; PieceType = King }
```

F#'s functional types all have structural equality, so you can see how this approach saves you from having to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Here, I also converted the 'factory' methods `whiteChecker`, `blackKing`, and so on, to *values*. The original functions always returned the same value, so I didn't see any reason to make them functions.

**Use built-in types**

The `Board` class is little but a wrapper around `Piece option list list`, so it can be eliminated. It can sometimes be useful to define a type alias:

```
type Board = Piece option list list
```

It can help you better communicate intent, but it doesn't preclude a user from providing a 'raw' `Piece option list list` value. This keeps things more flexible.

The only behaviour defined by `Board` are the two `Item` properties and the default board, all of which can easily be defined as `let`-bound values:

```
let row = List.item

let square coord = List.item coord.Row >> List.item coord.Column
```

Notice how `row` is nothing but an alias for `List.item`. Likewise, `square` is a composition of `List.item` functions. These functions are actually much more generic than the ones defined in the `Board` class, but they work correctly with a board as well.

You could define the default board like above, but perhaps you'll find the following more readable:

```
let defaultBoard = 
    [
        List.replicate 4 [None; blackChecker] |> List.concat
        List.replicate 4 [blackChecker; None] |> List.concat
        List.replicate 4 [None; blackChecker] |> List.concat
        List.replicate 8 None
        List.replicate 8 None
        List.replicate 4 [whiteChecker; None] |> List.concat
        List.replicate 4 [None; whiteChecker] |> List.concat
        List.replicate 4 [whiteChecker; None] |> List.concat
    ]
```

Code readability is subjective, but this is both shorter, and explicitly highlights the repetitive nature of the default board. On the other hand, as a reader, you can't 'see' the whole board laid out in the code.

In any case, you can get a row from the default board:

```
> row 2 defaultBoard;;
val it : Piece option list =
  [null; Some {Player = Black; PieceType = Checker;};
   null; Some {Player = Black; PieceType = Checker;};
   null; Some {Player = Black; PieceType = Checker;};
   null; Some {Player = Black; PieceType = Checker;}]
```

You can also get a single square:

```
> square { Row = 2; Column = 1 } defaultBoard;;
val it : Piece option = Some {Player = Black; PieceType = Checker;}
```

As far as I can tell, you could convert all the extension methods in `FSharpExtensions` to `let`-bound functions as well, but I think I'll conclude my review here.

**C# interop**

My general preference, if I need to expose an F# library to C# is to write the F# as idiomatically as possible. This means that I'll make no concessions to C# when writing my implementation.

Once I know what my F# implementation looks like, I can always slap an object-oriented [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) over the F# code, if necessary.

Some functional types, like records and sequences are easily consumable from C#, since they're simply immutable classes and `IEnumerable<T>` sequences, but other types, like discriminated unions, require more translation in order to look object-oriented.

Comment: Redefining `+` in a let-binding breaks the operator's normal usage. Try`let a = 1 + 1` beyond that definition. Such operator usage should be implemented as a static member, so that usages of the same operator on other types continue to resolve properly.