# American Checkers with AI

Tags: game, f#, ai, checkers-draughts

This is the third question in the series.  [Number 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/149796/34073) had most of the official two-player rules implemented, and [Number 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/150105/34073) was the basic UI.  This one has the complete two-player rules implemented, an AI using minimax with alpha-beta pruning.  All suggestions welcome, especially those that help me program in a more functionally and more cleanly.

**Checkers.fs** contains my basic types:

```
module public Checkers.Types
type Player = Black | White

type PieceType = Checker | King

type Coord = { Row :int; Column :int }

let offset c1 c2 =
        { Row = c1.Row + c2.Row; Column = c1.Column + c2.Column }

type Move = Coord List

type MoveTree = { Move :Move; Parent :Option<MoveTree>; Children :Option<List<MoveTree>> }

type internal AlphaBetaMove = { Alpha :float Option; Beta :float Option; Move :Move }
```

**Piece.fs** contains the information on a piece:

```
module public Checkers.Piece
open Checkers.Types

type Piece = { Player :Player; PieceType :PieceType }

let Promote piece = { Player = piece.Player; PieceType = King }

let whiteChecker = Some <| { Player = White; PieceType = Checker }
let whiteKing = Some <| { Player = White; PieceType = King }

let blackChecker = Some <| { Player = Black; PieceType = Checker }
let blackKing = Some <| { Player = Black; PieceType = King }
```

**Board.fs** contains a type alias and some helper methods:

```
module public Checkers.Board
open Checkers.Types
open Checkers.Piece
open System.Collections.Generic

type Board = Piece option list list

let square (coord :Coord) = List.item coord.Row >> List.item coord.Column

let rowFromSeq (value :'a seq) =
    Some (List.ofSeq value)

let listFromSeq (value :'a seq seq) =
    List.ofSeq (Seq.choose rowFromSeq value)

let defaultBoard = 
    [
        List.replicate 4 [None; blackChecker] |> List.concat
        List.replicate 4 [blackChecker; None] |> List.concat
        List.replicate 4 [None; blackChecker] |> List.concat
        List.replicate 8 None
        List.replicate 8 None
        List.replicate 4 [whiteChecker; None] |> List.concat
        List.replicate 4 [None; whiteChecker] |> List.concat
        List.replicate 4 [whiteChecker; None] |> List.concat
    ]
```

**FSharpExtensions.fs** contains a few functions that will be used by all the variants:

```
module internal Checkers.FSharpExtensions
open Checkers
open Checkers.Types
open System

let internal getJumpedCoord startCoord endCoord =
    { Row = startCoord.Row - Math.Sign(startCoord.Row - endCoord.Row); Column = startCoord.Column - Math.Sign(startCoord.Column - endCoord.Column) }

let internal moveIsDiagonal startCoord endCoord =
    startCoord <> endCoord &&
    System.Math.Abs(startCoord.Row - endCoord.Row) = System.Math.Abs(startCoord.Column - endCoord.Column)

let internal otherPlayer player =
    match player with
    | White -> Black
    | Black -> White
```

**AmericanCheckers.fs** contains the logic for American Checkers (or English Draughts, if you prefer):

```
module internal Checkers.Variants.AmericanCheckers
open Checkers.Types
open Checkers.Piece
open Checkers.Board
open Checkers.FSharpExtensions
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

[<Literal>]
let Rows = 7

[<Literal>]
let Columns = 7

let internal kingRowIndex(player) =
    match player with
    | Player.Black -> Rows
    | Player.White -> 0

let internal coordExists coord =
    coord.Row >= 0 && coord.Row <= Rows &&
    coord.Column >= 0 && coord.Column <= Columns

let internal checkMoveDirection piece startCoord endCoord =
    match piece.PieceType with
    | PieceType.Checker ->
        match piece.Player with
        | Player.Black -> startCoord.Row < endCoord.Row
        | Player.White -> startCoord.Row > endCoord.Row
    | PieceType.King -> true

let internal isValidCheckerHop startCoord endCoord (board :Board) =
    let piece = (square startCoord board).Value

    checkMoveDirection piece startCoord endCoord &&
    (square endCoord board).IsNone

let internal isValidKingHop endCoord (board :Board) =
    (square endCoord board).IsNone

let internal isValidCheckerJump startCoord endCoord (board :Board) =
    let piece = (square startCoord board).Value

    let jumpedCoord = getJumpedCoord startCoord endCoord
    let jumpedPiece = square jumpedCoord board

    checkMoveDirection piece startCoord endCoord &&
    (square endCoord board).IsNone &&
    jumpedPiece.IsSome &&
    jumpedPiece.Value.Player <> piece.Player

let internal isValidKingJump startCoord endCoord (board :Board) =
    let piece = (square startCoord board).Value

    let jumpedCoord = getJumpedCoord startCoord endCoord
    let jumpedPiece = square jumpedCoord board

    (square endCoord board).IsNone &&
    jumpedPiece.IsSome &&
    jumpedPiece.Value.Player <> piece.Player

let internal isValidHop startCoord endCoord (board :Board) =
    match (square startCoord board).Value.PieceType with
    | PieceType.Checker -> isValidCheckerHop startCoord endCoord board
    | PieceType.King -> isValidKingHop endCoord board

let internal isValidJump startCoord endCoord (board :Board) =
    match (square startCoord board).Value.PieceType with
    | PieceType.Checker -> isValidCheckerJump startCoord endCoord board
    | PieceType.King -> isValidKingJump startCoord endCoord board

let internal hasValidHop startCoord (board :Board) =
    let hopCoords =
        [
            offset startCoord {Row = -1; Column = 1};
            offset startCoord {Row = -1; Column = -1};
            offset startCoord {Row = 1; Column = 1};
            offset startCoord {Row = 1; Column = -1}
        ]

    let flattenedList = seq {
        for coord in hopCoords do
        yield coordExists coord && isValidHop startCoord coord board }

    flattenedList |> Seq.exists id

let internal hasValidJump startCoord (board :Board) =
    let jumpCoords =
        [
            offset startCoord {Row = -2; Column = 2};
            offset startCoord {Row = -2; Column = -2};
            offset startCoord {Row = 2; Column = 2};
            offset startCoord {Row = 2; Column = -2}
        ]

    let flattenedList = seq {
        for coord in jumpCoords do
        yield coordExists coord && isValidJump startCoord coord board }

    flattenedList |> Seq.exists id

let internal jumpAvailable player (board :Board) =
    let pieceHasJump row column =
        let piece = board.[row].[column]
        piece.IsSome && piece.Value.Player = player && hasValidJump { Row = row; Column = column } board

    let flattenedList = seq {
        for row in 0 .. Rows do
        for column in 0 .. Columns do
        yield (pieceHasJump row column) }

    flattenedList |> Seq.exists id

let internal moveAvailable (board :Board) player =
    let pieceHasMove row column =
        let piece = board.[row].[column]
        piece.IsSome &&
        piece.Value.Player = player &&
        (hasValidJump { Row = row; Column = column } board || hasValidHop { Row = row; Column = column } board)

    let flattenedList = seq {
        for row in 0 .. Rows do
        for column in 0 .. Columns do
        yield (pieceHasMove row column) }

    flattenedList |> Seq.exists id

let isWon (board :Board) =
    match (moveAvailable board) with
    | x when not <| x White -> Some Black
    | x when not <| x Black -> Some White
    | _ -> None

let internal setPieceAt coord piece (board :Board) =
    let boardItems = List.init (Rows + 1) (fun row ->
        match row with
        | i when i = coord.Row ->
            List.init (Columns + 1) (fun col ->
                match col with
                | j when j = coord.Column -> piece
                | _ -> board.[row].[col]
            )
        | _ -> board.[row]
    )

    boardItems

let internal jump startCoord endCoord (board :Board) =
    let kingRowIndex = kingRowIndex((square startCoord board).Value.Player)

    let piece =
        match endCoord.Row with
        | row when row = kingRowIndex -> Some <| Promote (square startCoord board).Value
        | _ -> (square startCoord board)

    let jumpedCoord = getJumpedCoord startCoord endCoord

    board
    |> setPieceAt startCoord None
    |> setPieceAt endCoord piece
    |> setPieceAt jumpedCoord None

let internal hop startCoord endCoord (board :Board) =
    let kingRowIndex = kingRowIndex (square startCoord board).Value.Player

    let piece =
        match endCoord.Row with
        | row when row = kingRowIndex -> Some <| Promote (square startCoord board).Value
        | _ -> (square startCoord board)

    board
    |> setPieceAt startCoord None
    |> setPieceAt endCoord piece

let internal playerTurnEnds (move :Move) (originalBoard :Board) (currentBoard :Board) =
    let lastMoveWasJump = Math.Abs(move.[0].Row - move.[1].Row) = 2
    let pieceWasPromoted = (square (List.last move) currentBoard).Value.PieceType = King &&
                            (square move.[0] originalBoard).Value.PieceType = Checker

    pieceWasPromoted ||
    not (lastMoveWasJump && hasValidJump (List.last move) currentBoard)

let public isValidMove startCoord endCoord (board :Board) =
    coordExists startCoord &&
    coordExists endCoord &&
    moveIsDiagonal startCoord endCoord &&
    (square startCoord board).IsSome &&
    match Math.Abs(startCoord.Row - endCoord.Row) with
    | 1 -> isValidHop startCoord endCoord board && not <| jumpAvailable (square startCoord board).Value.Player board
    | 2 -> isValidJump startCoord endCoord board
    | _ -> false

let public movePiece startCoord endCoord (board :Board) :Option<Board> =
    match isValidMove startCoord endCoord board with
    | false -> None
    | true ->
        match Math.Abs(startCoord.Row - endCoord.Row) with
        | 1 -> Some <| hop startCoord endCoord board
        | 2 -> Some <| jump startCoord endCoord board
        | _ -> None

let rec public moveSequence (coordinates :Coord seq) (board :Option<Board>) =
    let coords = List.ofSeq(coordinates)

    match board with
    | None -> None
    | Some b ->
        match coords.Length with
        | b when b >= 3 ->
            let newBoard = movePiece coords.Head coords.[1] board.Value
            moveSequence coords.Tail newBoard
        | _ -> movePiece coords.Head coords.[1] board.Value

let internal uncheckedMovePiece startCoord endCoord (board :Board) =
    match Math.Abs(startCoord.Row - endCoord.Row) with
    | 1 -> hop startCoord endCoord board
    | 2 -> jump startCoord endCoord board

let rec internal uncheckedMoveSequence (coordinates :Coord seq) (board :Board) =
    let coords = List.ofSeq(coordinates)

    match coords.Length with
    | b when b >= 3 ->
        let newBoard = uncheckedMovePiece coords.Head coords.[1] board
        uncheckedMoveSequence coords.Tail newBoard
    | _ -> uncheckedMovePiece coords.Head coords.[1] board
```

**AmericanCheckersAI.fs** contains the variant-specific logic for AI:

```
module Checkers.AIs.AmericanCheckersAI
open Checkers.Board
open Checkers.Variants.AmericanCheckers
open Checkers.Types
open System

let checkerWeights =
    [[0.0; 3.20; 0.0; 3.20; 0.0; 3.20; 0.0; 3.10];
    [1.15; 0.0; 1.05; 0.0; 1.0; 0.0; 1.10; 0.0];
    [0.0; 1.10; 0.0; 1.0; 0.0; 1.05; 0.0; 1.15];
    [1.15; 0.0; 1.05; 0.0; 1.0; 0.0; 1.10; 0.0];
    [0.0; 1.10; 0.0; 1.0; 0.0; 1.05; 0.0; 1.15];
    [1.15; 0.0; 1.05; 0.0; 1.0; 0.0; 1.10; 0.0];
    [0.0; 1.10; 0.0; 1.0; 0.0; 1.05; 0.0; 1.15];
    [3.10; 0.0; 3.20; 0.0; 3.20; 0.0; 3.20; 0.0]]

let kingWeights =
    [[0.0; 1.05; 0.0; 1.0; 0.0; 1.0; 0.0; 1.0];
    [1.05; 0.0; 1.10; 0.0; 1.05; 0.0; 1.05; 0.0];
    [0.0; 1.10; 0.0; 1.15; 0.0; 1.10; 0.0; 1.0];
    [1.0; 0.0; 1.15; 0.0; 1.20; 0.0; 1.05; 0.0];
    [0.0; 1.05; 0.0; 1.20; 0.0; 1.15; 0.0; 1.0];
    [1.0; 0.0; 1.10; 0.0; 1.15; 0.0; 1.10; 0.0];
    [0.0; 1.05; 0.0; 1.05; 0.0; 1.10; 0.0; 1.05];
    [1.0; 0.0; 1.0; 0.0; 1.0; 0.0; 1.05; 0.0]]

let isPlayerPiece player coord (board :Board) =
    let piece = square coord board
    piece.IsSome && player = piece.Value.Player

let nextPoint coord =
    match coord with
    | c when c.Row = Rows && c.Column = Columns -> None
    | c when c.Column = Columns -> Some {Row = c.Row + 1; Column = 0}
    | _ -> Some {coord with Column = coord.Column + 1}

let calculateCheckerWeight coord (board :Board) =
    let piece = (square coord board).Value
    let kingRow = kingRowIndex piece.Player

    let weight = 8.0 - (float <| Math.Abs(kingRow - coord.Row)) + (square coord checkerWeights)
    match piece.Player with
    | Black -> weight
    | White -> -weight

let calculateKingWeight coord (board :Board) =
    let piece = (square coord board).Value
    let weight = 8.0 + (square coord kingWeights)

    match piece.Player with
    | Black -> weight
    | White -> -weight

let calculatePieceWeight coord (board :Board) =
    let piece = square coord board
    match piece.Value.PieceType with
    | Checker -> calculateCheckerWeight coord board
    | King -> calculateKingWeight coord board

let calculateWeight player (board :Board) =
    let rec loop (weight :float) coord :float =
        match nextPoint coord with
        | Some c ->
            match isPlayerPiece player coord board with
            | true -> loop (weight + (calculatePieceWeight coord board)) c
            | false -> loop weight c
        | None -> weight

    loop 0.0 {Row = 0; Column = 0}

let calculateWeightDifference (board :Board) =
    let rec loop (weight :float) coord =
        match nextPoint coord with
        | Some c ->
            let piece = square coord board
            match piece.IsSome with
            | true -> loop (weight + (calculatePieceWeight coord board)) c
            | false -> loop weight c
        | None -> weight

    loop 0.0 {Row = 0; Column = 0}

let checkerJumps player =
    match player with
    | White -> [{Row = -2; Column = -2}; {Row = -2; Column = 2}]
    | Black -> [{Row = 2; Column = -2}; {Row = 2; Column = 2}]

let kingJumps player =
    (checkerJumps player) @
        (match player with
        | White -> [{Row = 2; Column = -2}; {Row = 2; Column = 2}]
        | Black -> [{Row = -2; Column = -2}; {Row = -2; Column = 2}])

let checkerHops player =
    match player with
    | White -> [{Row = -1; Column = -1}; {Row = -1; Column = 1}]
    | Black -> [{Row = 1; Column = -1}; {Row = 1; Column = 1}]

let kingHops player =
    (checkerHops player) @
        (match player with
        | White -> [{Row = 1; Column = -1}; {Row = 1; Column = 1}]
        | Black -> [{Row = -1; Column = -1}; {Row = -1; Column = 1}])

let getPieceSingleJumps coord (board :Board) =
    let piece = (square coord board).Value
    let moves = 
        match piece.PieceType with
        | Checker -> checkerJumps piece.Player
        | King -> kingJumps piece.Player

    let hops = List.ofSeq (seq {
        for move in moves do
        let endCoord = offset coord move
        yield
            match coordExists endCoord && isValidJump coord endCoord board with
            | true -> Some [coord; endCoord]
            | false -> None })

    List.map (fun (item :Option<Move>) -> item.Value) (List.where (fun (item :Option<Move>) -> item.IsSome) hops)

let rec createMoveTree (move :Move) (board :Board) =
    let moveTree =
        {
            Move = move;
            Parent = None;
            Children =
                let newBoard = if move.Length = 1 then board else uncheckedMoveSequence move board

                let newJumps = getPieceSingleJumps (List.last move) newBoard
                let newMoveEndCoords = List.map (fun item -> List.last item) newJumps

                let oldPieceType = (square move.Head board).Value.PieceType
                let newPieceType = (square (List.last move) newBoard).Value.PieceType

                match newMoveEndCoords.IsEmpty || (oldPieceType = Checker && newPieceType = King) with
                | false ->
                    let moves = List.map (fun (item :Coord) -> move @ [item]) newMoveEndCoords
                    let children = List.map (fun item -> createMoveTree item board) moves
                    Some children
                | true -> None
        }

    moveTree

let getPieceJumps coord (board :Board) =
    let moves = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Move>()

    let rec loop (moveTree :MoveTree) =
        match moveTree.Children with
        | None -> moves.Add(moveTree.Move)
        | Some t -> List.iter (fun item -> (loop item)) t

    let moveTree = createMoveTree [coord] board
    match moveTree.Children with
    | Some t -> loop <| createMoveTree [coord] board
    | None -> ()

    List.ofSeq moves

let getPieceHops coord (board :Board) =
    let piece = (square coord board).Value
    let moves = 
        match piece.PieceType with
        | Checker -> checkerHops piece.Player
        | King -> kingHops piece.Player

    let hops = List.ofSeq (seq {
        for move in moves do
        let endCoord = offset coord move
        yield
            match coordExists endCoord && isValidHop coord endCoord board with
            | true -> Some [coord; endCoord]
            | false -> None })

    List.map (fun (item :Option<Move>) -> item.Value) (List.where (fun (item :Option<Move>) -> item.IsSome) hops)

let calculateMoves player (board :Board) =
    let rec loop jumpAcc hopAcc coord =
        match isPlayerPiece player coord board with
        | true ->
            let newJumpAcc = getPieceJumps coord board @ jumpAcc
            match newJumpAcc with
            | [] ->
                let newHopAcc = getPieceHops coord board @ hopAcc
                match nextPoint coord with
                | Some c -> loop newJumpAcc newHopAcc c
                | None -> newHopAcc
            | _ ->
                match nextPoint coord with
                | Some c -> loop newJumpAcc [] c
                | None -> newJumpAcc
        | false ->
            match nextPoint coord with
            | Some c -> loop jumpAcc hopAcc c
            | None -> jumpAcc @ hopAcc

    loop [] [] {Row = 0; Column = 0}
```

**GameController.fs** contains the state of the game as a whole.  In the future, this will be expanded to tracking move history and other relevant information.

```
module public Checkers.GameController
open Checkers.Types
open Checkers.Board

type GameController = { Board :Board; CurrentPlayer :Player; CurrentCoord :Option<Coord> }

let newGame = { Board = Board.defaultBoard; CurrentPlayer = Black; CurrentCoord = None }
```

**Minimax.fs** contains the general logic for the AI's.  This module contains some very nasty code, including a few mutable variables.  I'm sure my other code is a mess as well, but I'd like special attention for this.

```
module internal Checkers.Minimax
open Checkers.Types
open Checkers.Board
open Checkers.FSharpExtensions
open Checkers.Variants.AmericanCheckers
open Checkers.AIs.AmericanCheckersAI

let rec internal bestMatchInList player highestDifference moveForHighestDifference (list :List<float * Move>) =
    let head::tail = list
    let weight = fst head

    let newMoveForHighestDifference =
        match player with
        | Black -> match weight > highestDifference with
                   | true -> snd head
                   | false -> moveForHighestDifference
        | White -> match weight < highestDifference with
                   | true -> snd head
                   | false -> moveForHighestDifference

    let newHighestDifference =
        (highestDifference, weight)
        ||> match player with
            | Black -> max
            | White -> min

    match tail with
    | [] -> (highestDifference, newMoveForHighestDifference)
    | _ -> bestMatchInList player newHighestDifference newMoveForHighestDifference list.Tail

let internal chooseNewAlpha currentAlpha (candidateAlpha :float Option) =
    match currentAlpha with
    | Some x -> if candidateAlpha.IsSome then Some <| max x candidateAlpha.Value else currentAlpha
    | None -> candidateAlpha

let internal chooseNewBeta currentBeta (candidateBeta :float Option) =
    match currentBeta with
    | Some x -> if candidateBeta.IsSome then Some <| min x candidateBeta.Value else currentBeta
    | None -> candidateBeta

let rec minimax player searchDepth alpha beta (board :Board) =
    match searchDepth = 0 || (isWon board).IsSome with
    | true ->
        let weightDifference = Some <| calculateWeightDifference board

        let newAlpha = if player = Black then weightDifference else alpha
        let newBeta = if player = White then weightDifference else beta

        { Alpha = newBeta; Beta = newAlpha; Move = [] }
    | false ->
        let moves = calculateMoves player board
        let mutable alphaForNode = None
        let mutable betaForNode = None

        let mutable newAlpha = alpha
        let mutable newBeta = beta
        let mutable move = []

        if searchDepth <> 0 then
            ignore <| List.map (fun x -> if newAlpha.IsNone || newBeta.IsNone || newAlpha.Value < newBeta.Value then
                                             let newBoard = uncheckedMoveSequence x board
                                             let alphaBetaMove = minimax (otherPlayer player) (searchDepth - 1) alphaForNode betaForNode newBoard

                                             match player with
                                             | Black ->
                                                 alphaForNode <- chooseNewAlpha alphaForNode alphaBetaMove.Alpha
                                                 newAlpha <- chooseNewAlpha newAlpha alphaForNode
                                                 move <- if newAlpha = alphaBetaMove.Alpha then x else move
                                             | White ->
                                                 betaForNode <- chooseNewBeta betaForNode alphaBetaMove.Beta
                                                 newBeta <- chooseNewBeta newBeta betaForNode
                                                 move <- if newBeta = alphaBetaMove.Beta then x else move

                                         ())
                               moves

        { Alpha = betaForNode; Beta = alphaForNode; Move = move }
```

**PublicAPI.fs** is really kind of a wrapper that containing methods that are meant to be called from outside the library.  On this note, note that all the `internal` methods are really meant to be private to the class, but xUnit doesn't support Portable Class Libraries (PCLs), so I need to expose them to the test library.

```
module public Checkers.PublicAPI
open Checkers.Variants
open Checkers.Types
open Checkers.Board
open Checkers.FSharpExtensions
open Checkers.Variants.AmericanCheckers
open Checkers.Minimax
open Checkers.GameController
open System

let isValidMove startCoord endCoord gameController =
    isValidMove startCoord endCoord gameController.Board &&
    (square startCoord gameController.Board).Value.Player = gameController.CurrentPlayer &&
    match gameController.CurrentCoord with
    | None -> true
    | coord -> startCoord = coord.Value

let movePiece startCoord endCoord gameController :Option<GameController> =
    let board = movePiece startCoord endCoord gameController.Board

    match (isValidMove startCoord endCoord gameController) with
    | true -> Some <|
                {
                    Board = board.Value;
                    CurrentPlayer = match playerTurnEnds [startCoord; endCoord] gameController.Board board.Value with
                                    | true -> otherPlayer gameController.CurrentPlayer
                                    | false -> gameController.CurrentPlayer        
                    CurrentCoord = match playerTurnEnds [startCoord; endCoord] gameController.Board board.Value with
                                   | true -> None
                                   | false -> Some endCoord
                }
    | false -> None

let move (move :Coord seq) (gameController) :Option<GameController> =
    let board = moveSequence move (Some gameController.Board)
    match board with
    | Some b -> Some <|
                {
                    Board = board.Value;
                    CurrentPlayer = match playerTurnEnds (List.ofSeq move) gameController.Board board.Value with
                                    | true -> otherPlayer gameController.CurrentPlayer
                                    | false -> gameController.CurrentPlayer        
                    CurrentCoord = match playerTurnEnds (List.ofSeq move) gameController.Board board.Value with
                                   | true -> None
                                   | false -> Some (Seq.last move)
                }
    | None -> None

let getMove searchDepth gameController =
    (minimax gameController.CurrentPlayer searchDepth None None gameController.Board).Move

let isWon controller =
    isWon controller.Board
```

Comment: Minimax is a fairly generic algorithm. I'm a little surprised to see so much game specific verbiage in that module.

Comment: All the game-specific stuff is off-loaded to the variants.  The minimax module is really only the minimax/alphabeta pruning logic, as far as I know.

Comment: Logicwise, yeah, but it's importing a bunch of checkers types.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to move toward injecting these values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't like these at all:

```
let internal chooseNewAlpha currentAlpha (candidateAlpha :float Option) =
    match currentAlpha with
    | Some x -> if candidateAlpha.IsSome then Some <| max x candidateAlpha.Value else currentAlpha
    | None -> candidateAlpha

let internal chooseNewBeta currentBeta (candidateBeta :float Option) =
    match currentBeta with
    | Some x -> if candidateBeta.IsSome then Some <| min x candidateBeta.Value else currentBeta
    | None -> candidateBeta
```

In our chat you state you were told to use `if` when matching against a simple boolean (there's no specific reason to use it over `match`, or `match` over it for that situation, so I'll not comment on that) but you can rewrite that with one `match` instead of a `match` with a nested `if`:

```
let internal chooseNewAlpha currentAlpha (candidateAlpha :float Option) =
    match (currentAlpha, candidateAlpha) with
    | (Some current, Some candidate) -> Some <| max current candidate
    | (Some current, None) -> Some current
    | (None, Some candidate) -> Some candidate
    | _ -> None

let internal chooseNewBeta currentBeta (candidateBeta :float Option) =
    match (currentBeta, candidateBeta) with
    | (Some current, Some candidate) -> Some <| min current candidate
    | (Some current, None) -> Some current
    | (None, Some candidate) -> Some candidate
    | _ -> None
```

Why `match` with a `Tuple`? Because `current` and `candidate` are codependent: each one can affect the result of the other. So we want to take both into account idiomatically.

---

```
let internal moveIsDiagonal startCoord endCoord =
    startCoord <> endCoord &&
    System.Math.Abs(startCoord.Row - endCoord.Row) = System.Math.Abs(startCoord.Column - endCoord.Column)
```

F# has an `abs` method: `startCoord <> endCoord && abs (startCoord.Row - endCoord.Row) = abs (startCoord.Column - endCoord.Column)`.

---

I would consider a refactor:

```
[<Literal>]
let Rows = 7

[<Literal>]
let Columns = 7
```

You use `Rows` and `0` in the same place, but now `0` doesn't make sense.

```
let internal kingRowIndex(player) =
    match player with
    | Player.Black -> Rows
    | Player.White -> 0
```

You should have:

```
[<Literal>]
Rows = 8

[<Literal>]
Columns = 8

[<Literal>]
FirstRow = 0

[<Literal>]
LastRow = Rows - 1

[<Literal>]
FirstColumn = 0

[<Literal>]
LastColumn = Columns - 1
```

Thus we have:

```
let internal kingRowIndex(player) =
    match player with
    | Player.Black -> LastRow
    | Player.White -> FirstRow
```

---

Some of your functions can take advantage of function composition:

```
let internal isValidJump startCoord endCoord (board :Board) =
    match (square startCoord board).Value.PieceType with
    | PieceType.Checker -> isValidCheckerJump startCoord endCoord board
    | PieceType.King -> isValidKingJump startCoord endCoord board
```

Could be something like:

```
let internal isValidJump startCoord endCoord (board:Board) =
    let jumpFunc =
        match (square startCoord board).Value.PieceType with
        | PieceType.Checker -> isValidCheckerJump
        | PieceType.King -> isValidKingJump

    jumpFunc startCoord endCoord board
```

---

```
let getPieceHops coord (board :Board) =
    let piece = (square coord board).Value
    let moves = 
        match piece.PieceType with
        | Checker -> checkerHops piece.Player
        | King -> kingHops piece.Player

    let hops = List.ofSeq (seq {
        for move in moves do
        let endCoord = offset coord move
        yield
            match coordExists endCoord && isValidHop coord endCoord board with
            | true -> Some [coord; endCoord]
            | false -> None })

    List.map (fun (item :Option<Move>) -> item.Value) (List.where (fun (item :Option<Move>) -> item.IsSome) hops)
```

Boy is *that* a mess.

You use a `for` loop (not F# idiomatic), filter *in* the `for` loop and return either `None` or `Some`, then use a `List.map` on a `List.where` to filter *only* the `Some` values and return the actual value.

You use a `List.where`, which is a synonym for `List.filter` (which is the preferred method), and the worst part is you use it on a list that could have already been filtered.

```
let getPieceHops coord (board :Board) =
    let piece = (square coord board).Value
    let moves = 
        match piece.PieceType with
        | Checker -> checkerHops piece.Player
        | King -> kingHops piece.Player

    let hopsFilter = List.filter (fun (head::tail) ->
        let startCoord = head
        let endCoord = tail |> List.head
        coordExists endCoord && isValidHop startCoord endCoord board)

    moves |> List.map (fun move -> [coord; offset coord move]) |> hopsFilter
```

We eliminated multiple excessive methods, and return the same thing you did initially. (Or should have.)

---

I've *finally* had time to review `minimax`, and I *think* this should be a suitable version that uses tail-call recursion and should do what you want.

Do note I've not tested this at all yet, this was a rewrite in *Notepad*. Something like the following *should* work, though you've mentioned to me in chat, so I've updated it substantially.

```
let rec minimax player searchDepth alpha beta (board:Board) =
    match searchDepth = 0 || (isWon board).IsSome with
    | true ->
        let weightDifference = Some <| calculateWeightDifference board
        let newAlpha = 
            match player with
            | Black -> weightDifference
            | _ -> alpha
        let newBeta =
            match player with
            | White -> weightDifference
            | _ -> beta
        { Alpha = newBeta; Beta = newAlpha; Move = [] }
    | false ->
        let rec loop alphaForNode betaForNode newAlpha newBeta move moves =
            match List.isEmpty moves with
            | true -> { Alpha = betaForNode; Beta = alphaForNode; Move = move }
            | false ->
                let currentMove = moves |> List.head

                match newAlpha.IsNone || newBeta.IsNone || newAlpha.Value < newBeta.Value with
                | false -> loop alphaForNode betaForNode newAlpha newBeta move (moves |> List.tail)
                | true ->
                    let newBoard = uncheckedMoveSequence currentMove board
                    let alphaBetaMove = minimax (otherPlayer player) (searchDepth - 1) alphaForNode betaForNode newBoard

                    match player with
                    | Black ->
                        let newAlphaForNode = chooseNewAlpha alphaForNode alphaBetaMove.Alpha
                        let newNewAlpha = choseNewAlpha newAlpha newAlphaForNode
                        let newMove = 
                            match newNewAlpha with
                            | a when a = alphaBetaMove.Alpha -> currentMove
                            | _ -> move
                        loop newAlphaForNode betaForNode newNewAlpha newBeta newMove (moves |> List.tail)
                    | White ->
                        let newBetaForNode = chooseNewBeta betaForNode alphaBetaMove.Beta
                        let newNewBeta = chooseNewBeta newBeta newBetaForNode
                        let newMove =
                            match newNewBeta with
                            | b when b = alphaBetaMove.Beta -> currentMove
                            | _ -> move
                        loop alphaForNode newBetaForNode newAlpha newNewBeta newMove (moves |> List.tail)
        let moves = calculateMoves player board
        loop None None alpha beta [] moves
```

Of course that's *huge* and does a lot of stuff. We obviously want to break it down.

So we'll extract our `match player with` to use some methods, function composition, etc.

It's still long, but it's *slightly* more maintainable.

```
let rec minimax player searchDepth alpha beta (board:Board) =
    match searchDepth = 0 || (isWon board).IsSome with
    | true ->
        let weightDifference = Some <| calculateWeightDifference board
        let newAlpha = 
            match player with
            | Black -> weightDifference
            | _ -> alpha
        let newBeta =
            match player with
            | White -> weightDifference
            | _ -> beta
        { Alpha = newBeta; Beta = newAlpha; Move = [] }
    | false ->
        let getNewValueAndMove chooseMethod nodeValue moveValue currentValue currentMove newMove =
            let newNodeValue = chooseMethod nodeValue moveValue
            let newValue = chooseMethod currentValue newNodeValue
            let finalMove = 
                match newValue with
                | a when a = moveValue -> currentMove
                | _ -> newMove
            (newNodeValue, newValue, finalMove)

        let rec loop alphaForNode betaForNode newAlpha newBeta move moves =
            match List.isEmpty moves with
            | true -> { Alpha = betaForNode; Beta = alphaForNode; Move = move }
            | false ->
                let currentMove = moves |> List.head

                match newAlpha.IsNone || newBeta.IsNone || newAlpha.Value < newBeta.Value with
                | false -> loop alphaForNode betaForNode newAlpha newBeta move (moves |> List.tail)
                | true ->
                    let newBoard = uncheckedMoveSequence currentMove board
                    let alphaBetaMove = minimax (otherPlayer player) (searchDepth - 1) alphaForNode betaForNode newBoard

                    match player with
                    | Black ->
                        let (newAlphaForNode, newNewAlpha, newMove) = getNewValueAndMove chooseNewAlpha alphaForNode alphaBetaMove.Alpha newAlpha currentMove move
                        loop newAlphaForNode betaForNode newNewAlpha newBeta newMove (moves |> List.tail)
                    | White ->
                        let (newBetaForNode, newNewBeta, newMove) = getNewValueAndMove chooseNewBeta betaForNode alphaBetaMove.Beta newBeta currentMove move
                        loop alphaForNode newBetaForNode newAlpha newNewBeta newMove (moves |> List.tail)
        loop None None alpha beta [] (calculateMoves player board)
```

---

Finally, `PublicAPI`: I *hate* the whitespace there, the way you indented that.

Generally, if I have to multi-line things like that I line break *and then* start indentation.

```
let movePiece startCoord endCoord gameController :Option<GameController> =
    let board = movePiece startCoord endCoord gameController.Board
    match (isValidMove startCoord endCoord gameController) with
    | false -> None
    | true ->
        Some <|
        {
            Board = board.Value;
            CurrentPlayer =
                match playerTurnEnds [startCoord; endCoord] gameController.Board board.Value with
                | true -> otherPlayer gameController.CurrentPlayer
                | false -> gameController.CurrentPlayer        
            CurrentCoord =
                match playerTurnEnds [startCoord; endCoord] gameController.Board board.Value with
                | true -> None
                | false -> Some endCoord
        }

let move (move :Coord seq) (gameController) :Option<GameController> =
    let board = moveSequence move (Some gameController.Board)
    match board with
    | None -> None
    | Some b ->
        Some <|
        {
            Board = board.Value;
            CurrentPlayer =
                match playerTurnEnds (List.ofSeq move) gameController.Board board.Value with
                | true -> otherPlayer gameController.CurrentPlayer
                | false -> gameController.CurrentPlayer        
            CurrentCoord =
                match playerTurnEnds (List.ofSeq move) gameController.Board board.Value with
                | true -> None
                | false -> Some (Seq.last move)
        }
```

It's a lot easier to follow. I also tend to put the single-line `match` patterns at the top, where it allows, so that there's not one line underneath a massive block like that just hanging out.

---

Overall it was quite good, excepting the few idiomatic issues.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> let internal hasValidJump startCoord (board :Board) =
>     let jumpCoords =
>         [
>             offset startCoord {Row = -2; Column = 2};
>             offset startCoord {Row = -2; Column = -2};
>             offset startCoord {Row = 2; Column = 2};
>             offset startCoord {Row = 2; Column = -2}
>         ]
>
>     let flattenedList = seq {
>         for coord in jumpCoords do
>         yield coordExists coord && isValidJump startCoord coord board }
>
>     flattenedList |> Seq.exists id
> ```

That iterates `jumpCoords` and produces a new list of booleans as to whether the conditions match.  That new list is then iterated to find if the condition ever returned `true`.  I can make that into one iteration with early return like:

```
let internal hasValidHop startCoord (board :Board) =
    let hopCoords =
        [
            offset startCoord {Row = -1; Column = 1};
            offset startCoord {Row = -1; Column = -1};
            offset startCoord {Row = 1; Column = 1};
            offset startCoord {Row = 1; Column = -1}
        ]

    let rec anyHopIsValid hops =
        let coord::tail = hops
        match coordExists coord && isValidHop startCoord coord board, tail with
        | true, _ -> true
        | false, [] -> false
        | false, _ -> anyHopIsValid tail

anyHopIsValid hopCoords
```

I can use the same principles to get rid of my multiple other `for`s, and noticeable reduce the runtime and make my code follow FP principles better.

---

Having `Board` be a `Piece Option List List` is very expensive since looking up an item in a list is \$O(N)\$.  Making this into a `Piece Option [,]` nearly halves the time to calculate a move.